# Simple question related to shading a feasible region

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

Sorry for the noobish question.

I have an inequality 
$x + 11y \ge1$

After I draw this line on a graph. I go back and use origin $(0,0)$ to check if the condition is true.
So since $0$ is not greater than or equal to 1, my condition is not true.Does that mean I shade above the line, in the region that doesn't contain $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality is $y \ge \frac{1-x}{11} $. The origin, $(0,0)$ is not true, and in fact any value below this line does not hold for this inequality. Try the point $(2,1)$ and you will find it satsifies it... this point is above the line.

So yes, the inequality holds for all values $(x,y)$ which are above the line. Hence you shade above the line, correct.

Comment: Thanks. My final exam is in two weeks and I keep second guessing everything and feel like I am forgetting the simple stuff I learned early on.

Comment: Try use http://www.wolframalpha.com  for questions like these - simply type the inequality like you did in your question into the search bar and it will show you the graph :)

Comment: Also, ive noticed with all of your questions on here that you have not selected a "best answer". If you are happy with a correct solution press the tick next to my answer. This helps other users know a solution has been found for this quesiton.

Comment: Will do thanks again